# GeoMesa on Kudu Import with spatial data error

Tags: scala, apache-kudu, geomesa

I use the example given in the tutorial to operate on my data, but after I import the data into Kudu, I find that the last field is not Geometry type. Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using your own data, correct? Likely the geometry is not valid WKT, which will result in a 'null' attribute. There is a handy website that you can use to validate your WKT strings [here](http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html)